# Question about textstat_simil and textstat_dist (Lit Review related)

Tags: quanteda

I apologize if this is a ridiculous question. I'm new to using Quanteda and getting my feet wet applying text mining to my field.

I'm trying to understand the difference between the textstat_simil and textstat_dist functions and was curious if there were some articles that I could read that would illuminate these. Most of the literature I'm finding treat the similarity and distance under the same umbrella and differentiate between methods like "cosine" and "Euclidean" in the same discussion. I was curious what is going on differently in quanteda.

Again, I apologize if this is a ridiculous question. I have found quanteda to be incredibly useful in guiding qualitative readings via quantitative topic narrowing, and just wanted to make sure I fully understood what was going on under the hood here. I've only been using the suite for a short while after switching from learning this content via NLTK.

Answer (score 1):

The difference comes from the maths behind and the general purpose of what distance and similarity are and how can they be measured.

`textstat_dist()` returns distance scores compute with euclidean or manhattan methods, etc. Euclidean distance for example measures how distant two things are in Cartesian space.

`textstat_simil()` returns similarity scores compute with cosine, correlation, jaccard, dice, etc. methods. These on the contrary tell you how two objects are similares.